# Silent and Still spell

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats

A simple scenario I thought of while learning how to GM Pathfinder, if a wizard takes the Still Spell feat alongside Silent Spell, will the effects be combined? And will the drawback on both being the spell takes a slot one level higher also combine, making it two levels higher?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can. Their effects combine, and the level gain is cumulative. See also:

[The SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/)

> Multiple Metamagic Feats on a Spell: A spellcaster can apply multiple metamagic feats to a single spell. Changes to its level are cumulative. You can’t apply the same metamagic feat more than once to a single spell.

Comment: In that case, it works exactly as I thought it would. Thank you!

Comment: @CalebHuggins do note that there are still obvious signs of spellcasting, as noted by the lead designer [here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l3vu?Jason-Is-concealed-spellcasting-possible-with#20). Summary: "[the rules] generally assume that the act of casting a spell has some noticeable element"